What exactly is the difference between bandwidth and speed?
I am currently studying QoS and I am often confused and tend to mix the terms "Bandwidth" and "Speed".
If I am not mistaken, bandwidth is the capacity of the link, correct? While the speed defines how fast the data is transmitted?
If that's the case, I am not quite sure if I understand what speed means here. If we have a link with a speed of 2 gbit/s, would it transmit data (lets say, 100 mbits) faster than a 1 gbit/s link? Or what if we (let's use our imagination here for a second) had a link with a BW of 1000 mbits but the speed would only be 500 mbit/s? The link's capacity would not be reached but it still wouldn't be able to transmit all 1000 mbits within a second, right?
Thank you for your time.

In my world, Mbit/s is speed (or "data rate"), MHz is bandwidth.

It's all about context. Basically, "bandwidth" is (as you write) usually about the capacity of a link or path, and "speed" can mean all sorts of things.

If we have a link with a speed of 2 gbit/s, would it transmit data (lets say, 100 mbits) faster than a 1 gbit/s link?

Here, "speed" is the link's nominal link rate. An Ethernet link with a nominal link rate of 1 Gbit/s (e.g. 1000BASE-T) already factors in the physical layer overhead, but it doesn't factor in the overheads of the higher layers.
For TCP over IPv4 with maximum-sized frames/packets, the calculation goes like this:

maximum Ethernet frame size including IPG = 1538 bytes
maximum Ethernet frame payload = IP MTU = 1500 bytes
IPv4 overhead (without options)  = 20 bytes
TCP overhead (without options) = 20 bytes
effective application payload = 1500-20-20 = 1460 bytes
effective application bandwidth = 1000 Mbit/s / 8 bit/byte / 1538 byte * 1460 byte = 118.7 Mbyte/s.

Now, "speed" could be applied to that bandwidth as well, as application throughput/speed. It could also mean a practically achievable speed in a given situation, regardless of potentially available network bandwidth (e.g. a given backup speed might be limited by I/O, not by SAN link speed).
So, if you need to be precise, make sure you include the exact layer or aspect where your bandwidth or speed should be applied.

Depending on context, "speed" might also be related to "latency". A link that has a higher bandwidth does not necessarily mean less latency, and might thus seem slower.
As an example, imagine two pieces of equipment 1 km apart. Too far for Ethernet, but to connect them you have the options a) laying a 9600 bps rs-232 cable or b) using a satellite service. As long as you're sending a few bytes per second, the 9600 bps option will always seem faster because it has much less latency - you can't get around the speed of light with the satellite service. Once you ramp up the (used) bandwidth, this changes.

Yet another aspect - "speed" as experienced by a user! However, only Ethernet over twisted pair is limited to 100 m. Ethernet over fiber easily runs over 10 km or even up to 100/200 km. And good luck with RS-232 over 1 km or even more. ;-) Also, GEO vs LEO satellites (traditional vs Starlink) makes a hell of a difference in latency.
